# TYPO3 7.6 - Pagebrowser missing in content element "Special Menus"

Tags: menu, typo3, backend

I am using TYPO3 7.6. I have set up a usergroup which can insert the content element "Special Menus". This group has access to a certain branch of the page tree and also has the right to see and edit every page.
Now a member of this group can insert the content element "Special Menus", 
but the page browser to select the pages (Selected Pages) for the menue is missing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### A short introduction:

The possibility to configure editing rights in TYPO3 are quite comprehensive. Most of it can be set in the *Backend Usergroups* (or single Backend users).

On the bottom of the tab *Access Lists* (in a Backend usergroup record), you can find the section *Page Content: Type*. Depending on the Install Tool setting `[BE][explicitADmode]`, you have to allow or deny content elements for editors here.

I understand that this was already done in your case.

### Your solution:

Above the mentioned section is a larger section with **Allowed excludefields**. Browse the panel *Page content* for the following setting:

```
Startingpoint (pages)
```

This setting has to be checked. It enables this field for non-admin backend users. It's the same for any other of these listed *excludefields*.

---

If enabling this field does not render your missing field, there could be another issue. With *TSconfig* it's also possible to disable backend fields, like that:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.pages.disabled = 1
```

This configuration would hide the field for all backend users, even administrators (if set globally).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, this was the solution.